# Viewing what properties exist in GeoJSON file loaded into MapShaper?

Tags: geojson, mapshaper

Suppose I have a large GeoJSON file loaded into Mapshaper. I want to convert a property to use as an ID field on export, but I don't know what the property naming schema is. The file is too large to conveniently check in a text editor.

Is there a way within Mapshaper to view available properties? I've tried using `-inspect`, but you have to select one record by a property -  which is hard when you don't know what the identifying property's name is! I can't find anything relevant searcing for properties in the [command reference](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **`-info`** in the MapShaper console using the Console button in the top right of the screen. It gives data including the properties for the first row.

[image]

It describes these as "attributes" in the docs, which is why searches on the term "properties" in the docs don't help. Here's the description from [the docs](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-info):

> ### `-info`
>
> Print information about a dataset. Useful for seeing the fields in a
>   layer's attribute data table. Also useful for summarizing the result
>   of a series of commands.
>
> ```
> # Example: Get information about an unknown GeoJSON or TopoJSON dataset
> mapshaper mystery_file.json -info
> ```